# how to execute sigma operation in python

Tags: python, algorithm, math, frequency

I am trying to create a function that computes this formula:

[image: $$distance = \sum_x{\frac{(obs_x - exp_x)^2}{exp_x}}$$].

Formula non-screenshot:

**distance = sigma * (( observed - expected)**2 / expected )**

This is my current code:

```
def distance(observed, expected):

    num = (observed - expected)**2
    den = (expected)
    dist = sigma * (num/den)

    return dist
```

I have no idea how I would compute sigma, so I appreciate any help/feedback!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you working with Python lists, or with some kind of array or series here? That is, what are `type(observed)` and `type(expected)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigma here means the sum over multiple observed and expected pairs.

For example:

If *observed* is a list of numbers [ 1,1,3,3,...]
and *expected* is a list of expected values corresponding to the observed values, say, [1.2,1.3,3.1,3.2...]

Then you are required to find the sum over their individual distances.

```
def distance(observed, expected):
    res = 0
    for o, e in zip(observed,expected):
        res += (o-e)**2/e

    return res
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you maybe explain what zip does? @Owlette

Comment: Or in one line `dist=sum( (o-e)**2/e for o, e in zip(observed,expected) )`.

Answer (score 0):

observed should be a list of number

```
def distance(observed, expected):
    return sum((item - expected)**2*1.0/ expected for item in observed )

observed = [1,3,45,56,3,2,4,5,6,7]
expected = sum(observed)/len(observed)
print distance(observed,expected)

274.461538462
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! Just a quick question though, could you possibly explain why you use "itemitem" instead of just "item"? @galaxyan

Comment: Judging by the formula the OP gives (where `exp` has a subscript `x`), `expected` should also be treated as a list. (I strongly supsect that the formula is for computing a chi-squared statistic.)

Answer (score 0):

Sigma is summation over the range and not the multiplication.
Observed and Expected must be list of numbers of same length.

```
def distance(observed, expected):
    sample_space_length = len(observed)
    distance = 0
    for x in range(sample_space_length):
        distance += ((observed[x] - expected[x]) ** 2) / expected[x]
    return distance
```